# Log for chromecast is not getting opened

Tags: chromecast

I am developing an application for google chromecast. When I am trying to debug the application, sometimes the log are coming on the URL:9222 link but sometimes this link is not even getting opened.
I haven't made any change to receiver app as well as the sender app. Is that any network related issue or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be running when you try to connect to port 9222; if chromecast is on home screen or another app is playing, you will not be able to connect.